# I'm having issues with converting an IP address from Decimal, to Binary, then to Dotted Decimal in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program that will take in any IP address be it decimal, dotted, or binary, then will convert it to it's dotted, decimal, or binary counterparts and display all 3.

Now I'm having some issues as to where in my code its going wrong. I don't get errors, just weird output. Anyways I thought maybe a fresh pair of eyes would do me some good as I've been at this all day and I'm getting tired.

Also a heads up, the whole point is to practice string manipulation so all input given to each function is a string and the function returns the results as a string.

**Code for converting a decimal saved a string into binary: **

```
//Converts a decimal address to a binary address.
string internet_address :: convertDecimaltoBinary(string decimal)
{
 //Variable to convert the decimal address string to an int.  
 int dec = stoi(decimal);

 //Instantiated variables
 int remain = 0;
 int count = 0;
 string bin;

 //While the decimal number doesn't equal 0
 while(dec)
 {
  //Collects what the remainder would be of the current decimal divided by 2.   
  remain = dec % 2;
  //Divides the current decimal by 2, stores the result back into the same variable.   
  dec /= 2;
  //Increases the count variable.
  count++;
  //Appends the remainder variable to the binary string.
  bin += to_string(remain);
  //If the count variable is equal to 8, it resets the variable to 0 and appends a space to the 
  binary string.
  if(count == 8)
  {
   count = 0;
   bin += " ";  
  }
 }
 //Returns the Bin string that contains the binary address.
 return bin;
}
```

**Code that converts the binary string into a Dotted Decimal string: **

```
//Converts a Binary address to a Dotted address
string internet_address :: convertBinarytoDotted(string binary)
{
 //Initializing variables
 string tempSect;
 string dot;
 long long binSect = 0;
 int remain = 0;
 int iterator = 0;
 int index = 0;
 int result;
 int base;

 //Runs until it completes every 8 digit section of the binary address.
 while(iterator != 4)
 {
  remain = 0;
  binSect = 0;
  result = 0;   
  base = 1;  

  //Scans through and gets every indiviudal section in the binary address.   
  for(index; index < binary.length(); index++)
  {
   if(binary[index] == ' ')
   {
    index += 1;
    break;   
   } 

  tempSect += binary[index];
 }

 //Converts the current binary section into a long variable type
 binSect = stoll(tempSect);

 //While the current section doesn't equal 0, it will conver the section into a number then append it
 //To the dotted address string.
 while(binSect)
 {
  remain = binSect % 10;
  binSect /= 10;

  result += remain*base;
  base *= 2;
 }

 if(iterator != 3)
 {
  dot += to_string(result) + ".";
 }

 else
 {
  dot += to_string(result);   
  } 
  //Increases the iterator variable, indicating the first section of the 
  string is complete.
  iterator++;
 }

 //Returns the completed dotted address.
 return dot;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and outputs?  As far as I know most of these aren't standard ways of writing an IP address, and while I can guess what you're trying to do from your code it would help to be explicit.

Comment: Also, can you give examples where it produces an output that's different from the output you want?

Comment: So I fed it just 12345 as a decimal address, the binary conversion worked fine and I got the correct output but then the dotted address came out as 137.987.987.987  which is weird because. Each number in a dotted address should be between 1 - 255.

Comment: Hmm I'm beginning to think maybe the binary isn't right. Its supposed to be a string that consists of 4 sections of 8 binary digits. Each section is separated by a space. I wonder if that's because the binary digit might have to auto fill some spaces with 0's to make up each section.